How to achieve bidirectional synchronization of local calendar data with Office 365 calendar data
Now I have a calendar program built based on mysql. Now I want to realize two-way Sync between local calendar data and office 365 calendar data. What should I do? Do I need to use CalDAV protocol to create a local server?
i need some advice,please help me
